# Remove Bind from live Broadcast

Tags: youtube-livestreaming-api

How can I remove a bind of a stream from a live broadcast? 
I cant find the code to remove a broadcast bind for python.
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveBroadcasts/bind

After that I want to bind that same broadcast with another stream

This is the code for a normal bind of a stream to a broadcast:

```
def bind_broadcast(youtube, broadcast_id, stream_id):
  bind_broadcast_response = youtube.liveBroadcasts().bind(
    part="id,contentDetails",
    id=broadcast_id,
    streamId=stream_id
  ).execute()

  print "Broadcast '%s' was bound to stream '%s'." % (
    bind_broadcast_response["id"],
    bind_broadcast_response["contentDetails"]["boundStreamId"])
```

Answer (score 0):

In YouTube Live Streaming API V3 documentation for `bind` function you find:

> The streamId parameter specifies the unique ID of the video stream that is being bound to a broadcast. If this parameter is omitted, the API will remove any existing binding between the broadcast and a video stream.

See: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveBroadcasts/bind

Comment: Hi, any conclusion if youtube allows to remove a bind from a live broadcast, and then set a new bind (allowing to change stream quality). Thanks!